# Mac Terminal Auto Complete

Tags: macos, terminal

Usually on a Unix/Linux terminal when you press <kbd>Tab</kbd> it will auto-complete until there are several options, and then it will list the options below for you to select. For example:

```
cd he
helpFolder/ helpMe/ heIsThere/
cd help
```

With the Mac terminal, it forces you to press it twice to see options. I wondering if it's possible to change that setting to one <kbd>Tab</kbd> press?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Put this in your `~/.inputrc`:

```
set show-all-if-ambiguous on
```

You'll need to restart your shell (for example by opening a new terminal window or typing `exec /bin/bash`).

Comment: where is  ~/.inputrc file

Comment: @Vikas simply type in nano ~/.inputrc or pico .inputrc to edit it. because of the period, the file is hidden so you won't see it in any browser

Comment: For those asking about ~/.inputrc file: just open the terminal and type `vim ~/.inputrc `

Comment: @VikasPandey `~/` is equal to your current user's home directory and is where you wanna store this type of settings file.

Answer (score 169):

1. Type in terminal `nano ~/.inputrc`
2. Paste the following on separate lines

   ```
   set completion-ignore-case on
   set show-all-if-ambiguous on
   TAB: menu-complete
   ```
3. Hit Control+O to save changes to .inputrc followed by control+X to quit
4. Open a new Terminal window or tab, or type “login” to open a new session with the rules in effect
5. Type and hit the tab key

Src: http://osxdaily.com/2012/08/02/improve-tab-completion-in-mac-os-x-terminal/

Comment: For other people who try this: I tried this in ~/.profile and got an error when I restarted: -bash: TAB: menu-complete: command not found. In .inputrc it worked fine.

Comment: is it possible to make it show all if it's ambiguous? right now when i tap tab twice for a blank directory it doesn't show anything

Comment: with all the three lines mentioned above, I am not able to get autocomplete working for my terminal, I did open it in a new window but it didn't work at all. Any clue why it doesn't work?

Comment: I was on zsh,, so changed my terminal to use bash and it started working

Answer (score 13):

I am adding a new answer  because in my case adding the line `set show-all-if-ambiguous on` was not enough.

I had also to remove the line: `TAB: menu-complete`.

My complete `~/.inputrc` file is the following:

```
set completion-ignore-case on
set show-all-if-ambiguous on
```

Comment: This solved my problem +1 with that tab (It was eager to autocomplete)

Answer (score 6):

What you want to change is the Bash shell setup. My OS version is 10.11.6 and I use mvim, here just vim or vi,if the ~/.inputrc does not exist, then you need create a new one.

1. In terminal type `vim /.inputrc`.
2. The variable of completion-ignore-case and show-all-if-ambiguous need to be enabled to be ON, this is done by paste those settings in two lines, `set completion-ignore-case on` and `set show-all-if-ambiguous on`
3. Add `TAB: menu-complete` and write&quit the vim. :wq
4. Quit the Terminal running, Command+Q.
5. Start Terminal again and verify the result.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like the other comments are for `bash` whereas MacOs moved already to `zsh` as default shell. To enable autocompletion (including subcommands), putting the following line in `zsh` config file (`~/.zshrc`) works for me:

```
autoload -Uz compinit && compinit
```

Answer (score 0):

1. code ./zshrc
2. '# Load Angular CLI autocompletion' and '# source <(ng completion script)'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).